# rviz ignores origin if it has decimal values

Tags: rviz, urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to modeling my first robot using URDF. The problem that I have is that when I visualize it with rviz, I can see that the joint's origins are ignored if they contains decimal points (for instance, something like "origin xyz="0 0 -0.08""). If, however, I use a comma to write decimal values on the origins (such as "origin xyz="0 0 -0.08""), everything works well.

This wouldn't be a problem if xacro didn't complain when I try to use math operations with comma decimals. So it is not clear to me if this is a bug on xacro, on rviz or if I am doing something wrong.

Anyone would have a clue of what can be happening?

For your reference, I am using ROS Lunar.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278144/rviz-ignores-origin-if-it-has-decimal-values/) by [javieralso](https://answers.ros.org/users/33018/javieralso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like an [internationalization](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) problem. If you open a Python console, and type `float('0.08')` and `float('0,08')` I imagine the latter will work.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [javieralso](https://answers.ros.org/users/33018/javieralso/) on 2017-12-26**:
Thanks David!!

You were right, I just messed up with my locale configuration. As soon as I fixed it, it worked :D

Thanks!!

Javier